# Can questions about PHP work environments be on topic?

Tags: support, specific-question

The specific questions I'd like to ask is how to prepare for PHP jobs since a) PHP is not fully OO AFAIK and b) There're no frameworks in the regular sense of other programming languages concept of frameworks. Now do you think that this spec question is something I can ask or should I avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean by "there are no frameworks in the regular sense of other programming languages concept of frameworks"?

Comment: Let's start by proving one of your assumptions, then we can see what questions are available to you after that: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196079/are-there-any-large-scale-enterprise-frameworks-for-php Sometimes asking a question is like development, you have to break it down into smaller problems, and work on them individually.

Comment: And you have your answer; your assumption was incorrect. Also PHP is fully OO last time I checked, and while the Q I wrote got an answer listing the 2 most common frameworks, there are literally hundreds I am told that are full featured robust frameworks. All of that said, do you even have a question to ask now? If so, has it changed by way of illumination?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: That was pretty cheeky, asking a shopping question as a science experiment. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey was on the fence as a shopping question because I would have accepted "Yes" or "No" as an answer so long as either one had a touch of explanation